# How to convert Map<String,String> to "key1:value1,key2:value2,.." using lambda

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8

I have a `Map<String,String>` and I need to convert it to a single `String`: `"key1:value1,key2:value2,..."`.

I can do this using iteration. But can I do this using new lambda and stream functionality of java 8? Thanks!

Comment: @Anonymous downvoters: It would be nice and helpfull, if you could explain the downvote. Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are because you didn't show any attempt to do it with streams.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a map and a joining collector

```
Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");
String text = map.entrySet().stream()
                 .map(e -> e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue())
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(text);
```

prints

```
key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3
```

BTW I wouldn't use String.format() if you can avoid it as it can be much slower than String concatenation.

Answer (score 7):

```
Map<String, String> map = ...;
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> String.join(":", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```